# How to limit the output of a variable with in a caption?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm working with this line:

```
Me.Label_SSN.Caption = "You Selected " & ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1) & "Click 'Turn In' Below."
```

For `& ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1) &` some times the output is very long. With out changing the size of the label, how would you limit the text from it?

For example `You Selected Something to long Click 'Turn In' Below.` would read out more like `You Selected Somethi... Click 'Turn In' Below.`

Another question I have is: are you able to change the color of text mid-line and then change it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
Me.Label_SSN.Caption = "You Selected " & _
              IIf(Len(ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1)) > 10, _
                  Left(ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1), 7) & "...", _
                  ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1)) & _
              " Click 'Turn In' Below."
```

---

I'm not sure whether you can change the colour of certain characters in labels.

Comment: This is perfect. Just one question with your code. What does the `IIf` do that is different from just `If`.

Comment: @WilliamSmith `If` is a statement.  `IIf` (which stands for "inline If") is a function that takes three parameters - if the first (Boolean) parameter is `True`, the function returns the second parameter, otherwise it returns the third parameter.

Comment: @WilliamSmith  So the first parameter I passed was `Len(ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1)) > 10`, which will obviously be true if the length of your variable is more than 10.  The second parameter is `Left(ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1), 7) & "..."` which is what you want to display if the length is greater than 10.  And the third parameter is `ListBox_Tools_Out.List(r, 1)` which is what you want to display if the length is less than 11.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. Tho I already did a bit of googling to figure it out. It also would seem like text color change is impossible. Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: If you wanted the text in a specific location to be a different colour - e.g. the part of that Label which contains the ListBox_Tools_Out value, you could always set up three labels, with appropriate colours, and set the caption of the first one to be "You selected", the caption of the second one to be whatever the `IIf` function returns, and the caption of the third one to be "Click 'Turn In' Below."